# How to write a simple gridview in java?

Tags: java, sql, gridview

I wrote sql but it takes more time when execute it in jsp. And I want to make faster it. Will grid view make the page faster?
I'm junior in Java. I researched in google but didn't find clear sample about gridview. Can u help me?

Comment: Do you have to use plain JSP (with JSTL) or can you use a web framework like Spring or JSF? Also, what have you tried? And please, don't use scriptlets for your solution (that Java code inside `<% %>` tags in the JSP).

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a web based application backed by the DB.

Note that gridview is not something offered by Java, instead you can create tables by using your web frameworks and render data there.

You say, it takes a lot of time to execute an SQL when running withing JSP. Where the time goes?

Running the SQL itself? Maybe creating a JSP or transmitting it to the client browser in an Html form, or even maybe the rendering of your table in browser?

You should detect the bottleneck in order to understand what you're going to fix
Consider to use profiler and see (at least on server vm) where the time goes.
I think JVisualVM will suit your needs here.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this task using following steps

1. Create one servlet.
2. Connect to the database and fetch the data which we have to display.
3. Create a list and keep the data in list it.
4. Set the list in request and forward the control to JSP.
5. On JSP, use [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) to show the data in grid form.

Hope this helps you.